# Selecting element by text and attribute

Tags: jquery

Simple question: why does this not work?

```
if ($('a:contains("some text"):first').attr("class") == "someclass") { 
    this.css('background-color', 'red');  
}
```

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? If it's not a jQuery object, that's a problem. We would need to ideally see your HTML to give you a better answer.

Comment: This should refer to the <a> element which is found in the first line.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how the scoping of the `this` keyword works. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `this` should refer to the <a> element which is found in the first line.

Unfortunately that's not how the scoping of the `this` keyword works. In this case `this` will refer to the containing scope of wherever this code is placed. To do what you require you would need to reference the `a` element directly. Try this:

```
var $a = $('a:contains("some text"):first');
if ($a.attr("class") == "someclass") { 
    $a.css('background-color', 'red');  
}
```

Also note that if the `a` element selected has multiple classes the above will fail. To fix that you can use jQuery's `hasClass()` method:

```
var $a = $('a:contains("some text"):first');
if ($a.hasClass("someclass")) { 
    $a.css('background-color', 'red');  
}
```

Or, better yet, you could select the element directly by the class you're looking for without the need of the `if` statement.

```
$('a.someclass:contains("some text"):first').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Finally note that it is better practice to define your style rules in a separate stylesheet and then use `addClass()` to add those classes where required in JS instead of adding them ad-hoc using `.css()`.